# Is there a way to view a specific item in an already mapped array in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Im in a bit of a bind here and can use some help. Im mapping over an array of items that I got back from an API call, and I render it to the dom as such:

```
render() {
    const newsItems = this.props.news.map((article) => {
      return (
        <Row>
          <Col xs="auto">
            <Card
              id={article.id}
              style={{
                height: "40%",
                width: "40%",
                border: "solid",
                margin: "2rem",
              }}
            >
              <CardImg
                top
                width="100%"
                src={article.urlToImage}
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>
                  <strong>{article.title}</strong>
                </CardTitle>
                <CardSubtitle>Athor: {article.author}</CardSubtitle>
                <CardText>{article.description}</CardText>
                <Button color="primary" size="lg" active>
                  View Article
                </Button>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      );
    });
```

im having difficulty making the view article button work, to view that one particular mapped article in a separate component, I can't seem to pass the information needed. Any help would be appreciated. Also, if it helps, im using redux. Its just that once its mapped, I can't seem to set that button to know what article is clicked to display the information from the array for that particular article.

Comment: I'm sure at least that you are getting a warning about not using the key in the map :)

Comment: What does the button actually do - what function does it trigger? The general workflow is that the button takes the `article.id`, and passes it to some state (probably in Redux in your case) that the other component can access. The other component then accesses that article by id from the array/object you are storing them all in (again, probably in Redux).

Comment: at the moment, the button does nothing, i tried passing onclick the ID but it can't access it